# What is the best way to keep dimensionality when subarraying numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, array-indexing

Suppose I had a standard numpy array such as

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape((2,3))
```

When I subarray the array, by performing such task as

```
a[1, :]
```

I will lose dimensionality and it will turn into 1D and print, `array([3, 4, 5])`

Of course the list being 2D you originally want to keep dimensionality. So Ihave to do a tedious task such as

```
b=a[1, :]
b.reshape(1, b.size)
```

**Why does numpy decrease dimensionality when subarraying?**

**What is the best way to keep dimensionality, since `a[1, :].reshape(1, a.size)` will break?**

Comment: How about `a[[1], :]`?

Comment: What are trying to do with the subarray that requires keeping that size 1 dimension?  What's wrong with treating a row (or column) as a 1d array?

Comment: `a[1:2, :]` also works (see John Zwinck's answer).  I'm sure this question is a duplicate, but it will require the right search terms to find the previous questions.

Comment: @Divakar makes a copy, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use slicing rather than indexing, and the shape will be preserved:

```
a[1:2]
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It seems correct unless I'm misunderstanding the question..

Comment: @MarkMeyer: It is correct, but there is no intelligence or ethics test as part of the Stack Overflow account creation process, so sometimes you see illegitimate downvotes.  Oh well.

Comment: Indeed, perfect, simple.

Comment: Actuallly,, I like `a[1, None]` better, especially if the index is not `1` but a more complicated expression. You don't really want to type something like `a[n*m*(k-1) + m*(l-1) + u :  n*m*(k-1) + m*(l-1) + u + 1]`, right?

Comment: What is the difference between slicing and indexing?

Comment: @J.Doe: Indexing reduces dimensions.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I mean, what is the difference between the two like in meaning. I tried googling difference between indexing and slicing for Python and get 0 results :/

Comment: @J.Doe: Imagine you have a list of students.  Indexing means "Choose the Nth student."  Slicing means "Choose the Nth through Pth students."  That's why indexing reduces dimensions but slicing does not.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with John Zwinck's answer, I wanted to provide an alternative in case, for whatever reason, you are forced into using indexing (instead of slicing).

OP says that "`a[1, :].reshape(1, a.size)` will break":

You can add dimensions to numpy arrays like this:

```
b = a[1]
# array([3, 4, 5]
b = a[1][np.newaxis]
# array([[3, 4, 5]])
```

(Note that `np.newaxis` *is* `None`, but it's a lot more readable to use the `np.newaxis`)

---

As pointed out in the comments (@PaulPanzer and @Divakar), there are actually many ways to accomplish this same thing (again, with indexing instead of slicing):

These ones do not make a copy (data changed in each affect `a`)

```
a[1, None]
a[1, np.newaxis]
a[1].reshape(1, a.shape[1]) # Use shape, not size
```

This one does make a copy (data is independent from `a`)

```
a[[1]]
```

Comment: `a[1][None]` creates an unnecessary intermediate. `a[1, None]` or `a[None, 1]` is much better.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I've updated my answer to reflect some of the comments throughout the page